# Строение слов

Tags: корень-слова

всхлив

Comment: А что это слово означает? Могли бы Вы привести примеры его употребления, тогда Вам скорей всего и ответят.

Comment: И потрудитесь нормально сформулировать вопрос. Уважайте хоть немного тех, кто будет отвечать.

Comment: Не встречал такого слова.Скорее всего, его не существует в литературном языке.

Comment: Когда человек всхлипывает, он нечетко призносит слова)))

Answer (score 1):

Если это всхлип,то всё слово - корень+нулевой суффикс+ нулевое окончание. Это слово образовалось от глагола всхлипывать без суффикса (или с помощью нулевого суффикса). В литературном языке без приставки не употребляется. Хлип-хлипать-хлюп-хлюпать - просторечия, вот в молдавском и украинском, вероятно, есть. В словарях очень редко его встретишь, но в "Школьном грамматико-орфографическом словаре р.языка"Панова и Текучёва есть всхлип/ну/ть, всхлип/ыва/ть.(у меня только на бумажном носителе, ссылку на словари в Интернете дать не могу).

Answer (score 0):

Если это слово "всхлип", то здесь корень "хлип" (хлипкий) и приставка "вс", нулевое окончание

Comment: Хлипкий-другое значение - слабый, а всхлип-вздох при плаче, вероятно, от звукоподражания.

Comment: >Толковый словарь Ушакова

>**ХЛИПАТЬ**, хлипаю, хлипаешь, несов. (простореч.). Сдерживая плач, издавать прерывистые, всхлипывающие звуки.